# Probability of a sample from a random variable with Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, approximation

I am studying a paper [[1]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.187.5145&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which states that, as far as I understand, the probability of a single sample $x$ taken from a random variable $X$ with Gaussian distribution equals the Gaussian distribution density function

$$ \Pr(X=x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left\{-\dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}$$

where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

(If you think my formulation is incorrect or imprecise, feel free to correct me and please have a look to Equation 1 of Section 3.1 in [1].)

If I remember correctly my math classes, the probability of a certain sample in a continuous probability distribution approaches zero, because probability (at least for ranges of X) is defined as the integral over the density function.

Is the approximation used in the referenced paper valid? What are the constraints, if there are some?

Addon: In this paper, they do the same for the probability of a sample in an exponential probability distribution (see Equation 2 of Section 3.2 in [1]).

Comment: A density is not a probability: some densities can be more than $1$ for some values of $x$ while a probability cannot be.  I do not see a claim in your cited paper that this density is a probability.

Comment: per the comment above, what you write as $Pr(x)$ isn't a probability. It defines a curve $f(x)$ whose values you can plot for any $x$ from -infinity to +infinity. It's the _area under the curve_ between any two values of x, x1 and x2, that is the probability that x takes a value between x1 and x2.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for your comments. In the paper, I read right at the beginning of Section 3.1 the following sentence: "For map matching, given a location measurement $z_t$, there is an emission probability for each road segment $r_i$, $p(z_t|r_i)$." This probability is later defined as $p(z_t|r_i)=1/(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_z)e^{-0.5(||z_t-x_{t,i}||_{great\ cricle}/\sigma_z)^2}$. (Note that $x_{t,i}$ is a hypothesis of the current position which is the expectation of the GPS measurement $z_t$.) To me it seems exactly as what I explained in my question. Did I misunderstand something?